# Connection string for MS Access to Azure SQL Server 2012

Tags: ms-access, azure-sql-database, dsn

[image]

I need to make a simple MS Access front end to connect to a SQL Server 2012 on the cloud (Azure).

I have tried to use the external data/odb connection, but am having problems formatting/developing the connection string.

I have all the information, I just don't know the way it should be listed using ODBC.

I've attached a screen shot where the connection string needs to go.

I know how to write the connection from .net but not from odbc.

How should this be laid out?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [SQL Azure page at connectionstrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-azure/), the connection string should look something like this:

```
Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};
Server=tcp:[serverName].database.windows.net;Database=myDataBase;
Uid=[LoginForDb]@[serverName];Pwd=myPassword;Encrypt=yes;
```

They also add the comment

> Use 'username@servername' for the User ID parameter. Servername is the servername portion of the server parameter, i e 'myNamedServer' of tcp:myNamedServer.database.windows.net

Their example uses `SQL Server Native Client 10.0`, but I expect that `SQL Server Native Client 11.0` would work the same way.

Comment: Thanks to your post I figured out how it is supposed to be laid out.
DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0}
Server=ServerName
Database=DatabaseName
uid=UserId
Password=UserPassword

I posted it just in case someone else is having problems